# Create infopath form using visual studio 2012 and bind it to list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, visual-studio-2012

Can we create infopath form with visual studio ? and can we bind the same with list ? please give me some links to do this task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an Info-path form but only using form based approach, it allows you to add code using visual studio, Also make sure when you install MS office you choose the option of Office development tools in Visual Studio. Then only you will get the option in info-path for coding.

You can also check the below link.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee526362.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can create a form template and then play around with it as it pleases you, then publish it to a specific list if you want,

Here's MSDN post to get you started,

[Walkthrough: Creating a Basic Form Template with Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa942693.aspx)